# Neo4j/Cypher: Extracting the last item of a StringArray (This what neo4j called it)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, cypher-3.1

Lets say I have a node with a property, `Event`, that is assigned a StringArray. I am trying to extract '6013' and '6005' that were assigned from a collection when the node was created ( see below for creation query code) and assign them to as another property.

I tried using `SPLIT` but it does not work with what neo4j refers to as StringArray.

`Event: ["EventLog/6013", "EventLog/6005"]`

**Creation Query: Event assigned from collection**

`...
WITH act.timestamp as timestamp, COLLECT(DISTINCT act.message) as messages, COLLECT(DISTINCT obt.filename) as filenames, COLLECT(act) as acts
CREATE (a{ Event: filenames, Description:messages, timestamp:timestamp})
FOREACH (act in acts | CREATE (act)-[:LINK]->(a))`

**Desired Node:**

`Event: ["EventLog/6013", "EventLog/6005"]
 Assinged: [6013, 6005]`

Comment: Just a note, there's really never any good case for creating a node without a label. Definitely add a label in your CREATE clause for the node, that way you can look up that node faster when supplying the label (using a label scan), and if quicker lookup is needed you can create an index on a label/property combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [list comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension) to do an extraction/transformation of each item in your list (`extract()` can do the same, but I prefer the list comprehension syntax).

From there it's a matter of what rules to follow to get the value you need from the string.

If the values are always 4 digits, and there's never any trailing whitespace, then you can use `right(event, 4)` to get the last 4 characters of the string.

If the digits can be of varied size, but the prefix for each string is always "EventLog/", then you can use `substring(event, 9)` to get the substring after the 9th character.

If the prefix could vary and all you knew was that the part you wanted was after the first "/" character, then you could use split(), getting the second part of the resulting list like this: `split(event, '/')[1]`.

In any case, if you wanted the value as an integer rather than a string, you'd need to use `toInteger()` on the result.

Here's an example of using list comprehension using the `right()` function:

```
WITH ["EventLog/6013", "EventLog/6005"] as events
RETURN [event in events | toInteger(right(event, 4))] as extractedValues
```